# WaveData LWJGL3

Tags: java, audio, lwjgl, openal

I am trying to load sound in LWJGL 3 according to this tutorial ( http://wiki.lwjgl.org/index.php?title=OpenAL_Tutorial_1_-_Single_Static_Source ), but I found a problem that the class WaveData, which was most probably in the older version of LWJGL 2.X, is not there. There for I cant even compile the code. Is there any other way how to load sounds in lwjgl using openAL...

in LWJGL 2 I used to use paulscode sound system ( http://www.paulscode.com/forum/index.php?topic=4.0 ) but I am not sure if it works now in the newer version of LWJGL 3. Thank you for your answer :)

and if there would be any tutorial around sound in lwjgl3, could you please include the link in your answer, I tried googling theese tutorials for ages but I failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a [forum post](http://forum.lwjgl.org/index.php?topic=5652.msg30029#msg30029) it is stated:

> LWJGL3 doesn't include the WaveData from LWJGL2 but it still works the same in LWJGL3, just grab it from the LWJGL2 source code and include it in your project.

So it should be safe to just copy the old WaveData class and use it with LWJGL3, because the loading algorithm and OpenAL internals have not been changed.

---

Recently, LWJGL included bindings for the [STB](https://github.com/nothings/stb) library. This provides a set of utility functions for different things, like image loading, font loading and perlin noise calculation. It also has an [Ogg Vorbis Decoder](http://javadoc.lwjgl.org/org/lwjgl/stb/STBVorbis.html). Be warned however, that, like OpenGL and GLFW, STB provides only static functions instead of an object-oriented interface. It is also not very optimized.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply, is it really the neatest way how to load sound into lwjgl3 ?